# How can I define the Matsum command or what is the error caused?

Tags: python, numpy

```
  import numpy as np

  a=np.array([[36,98,54],
              [75,89,15],
              [37,94,63]])
  b=np.array([[53,56,93],
              [12,45,66],
              [19,28,89]])
  c=matsum(a,b)
  print(c)
```

---

**Matsum says it is not defined, but i imported the numpy library?**

```
   ----> 8 c=matsum(a,b)
     
   NameError: name 'matsum' is not defined
```

Comment: `np.matsum`....

Comment: do you mean something like this `a+b`?

Comment: yes it is `a+b`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is what you are looking for:

```
import numpy as np

a = np.array([[36, 98, 54],
              [75, 89, 15],
              [37, 94, 63]])
b = np.array([[53, 56, 93],
          [12, 45, 66],
          [19, 28, 89]])
c = np.add(a, b)
print(c)
```

or just do what @Shubham Shaswat suggested:
import numpy as np

```
a = np.array([[36, 98, 54],
              [75, 89, 15],
              [37, 94, 63]])
b = np.array([[53, 56, 93],
          [12, 45, 66],
          [19, 28, 89]])
c = a + b
print(c)
```

both return

```
[[ 89 154 147]
 [ 87 134  81]
 [ 56 122 152]]
```